# keep from position 5 to 15 of an rdd

Tags: apache-spark, filter

Lets say i have this dataframe :

```
myDataFrame.map(r =>
  (
    ( r.getAs[String]("col1"),
      r.getAs[String]("col2"),
      r.getAs[String]("col3"),
      r.getAs[String]("col4")
    ),
    r.getAs[Int]("col5")))
  .groupByKey()
  .map(r => (r._1, r._2.sum))
  .sortBy(r => r._2)
  .map(r => {
    Chart(r._1._1, r._1._2, r._1._3, r._1._4)
  })
  .toDF("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")
```

This returns 1000 dataframes 
I'd like to keep and return only dataframes from index 10 to 100 .
Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A `Dataset` isn't really indexed. How would you define the index over multiple partitions? Plus the data can be shuffled at any time and change the "index". If you just want to take a limited number of elements, use the `take(n: Int)` method.

Comment: my intention was to make that king of filter after the sort.
OK for the take but what about a range ? I mean once sorted only between 10 to 100

Comment: I don't think there's anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

If rows are unique, "limit" with "except" can work (no guarantee):

```
val df = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).toDF("sortable")
df.limit(4).except(df.limit(2))
```